# Merge Input Text with Input Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to merge an input text with the input image like this image
[Intended Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeHtm.png)

My situation is something like this: [My Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBlRk.png)

I already tried to follow this tutorial, which does something similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv0AiWFAiRg&t=410s

But I didn't get the expected result.

Here is my code:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0rZ.png)

[CSS-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wyBb.png)

[CSS-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGMON.png)

[CSS-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqbAc.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the magnifier glass in a wrapper with the text input. Since you didn't upload any actual code with it, here it is with a stock image:

```css
#search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 16px;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  
  left: 6px;
  
  margin: auto 0;
}

#search-input {
  padding-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-wrapper">
  <input id="search-icon" type="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Magnifying_glass_icon.svg/1200px-Magnifying_glass_icon.svg.png">

  <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="input thingy">
</div>
```

The icon should have an absolute positioning *within* the wrapper, thus the relative positioning in the wrapper. To center it between the top and bottom, its margin is set to `auto` for both the top and bottom margin, this is supported by the position being set to 0 on top and bottom. The padding on the input is relative to how much space the icon takes up. In this case 6px for the left and right "margin" and 16px for the width.